# Saving VC on closing (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a yes "VC" (**standard** and **scientific**).

How can I make it so that when you go into the **scientific** (or **standard**) and close the application, then the next time you open the  "VC" where the application was closed?

I'm using **SWRevealViewController**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're storing a user choice, add a flag to UserDefaults that stores the choice. When the app starts, use the value that you've stored in UserDefaults to show the correct VC.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the view controller identifier in UserDefault.

Set that vc as front view controller to SWReveal in didFinishLaunch as usual we do.